# Combine python f-string with format

Tags: python, f-string

I want to calculate math operation in a f-string using a variable passed to `format` method. For example i need something like :

```
print(f"{{a}} * 3".format(a=2))
```

This code prints:

```
2 * 3
```

But i want the result that's 6. Also i wont use python `eval` function to evaluate this string.

Answer (score 12):

As stated by [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions):

> The `str.format()` "expression parser" is not suitable for use when implementing f-strings.

While you could do something like:

```
name = "John"
age = 30
print(f'My name is {{0}} and I am 5 years older than {age - 5}'.format(name))
```

what you asked for in your original question is not doable.

You can also read [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3kezyg/why_not_combine_fstring_with_strformat/) to see why that would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: Ah, nice find with that PEP 498 excerpt. I was looking for something like that to explain why you can't use: `print(f"{a * 3}".format(a=2))`. +1

Answer (score 6):

You need to put the `3` in curly braces as well:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> print(f"{a * 3}")
6
>>>
```

Comment: @AlirezaAfzalaghaei Although I admit haven't tried _every_ way, I'm pretty sure you can't. The whole purpose of using f-strings is to avoid the `str.format` method. Also, you never made it clear you _had_ to use the `str.format` method. Please state all your requirements in your question before hand next time.

Comment: @Alireza Afzal aghaei `print(f"{a * 3}".format(a=2))` does work but what's the purpose of the f-strings then?

Comment: @whiteredblack I thought so to, but that's not the case. Running `print(f"{a * 3}".format(a=2))` raises `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Comment: Ok, Actually i can't create any variable. Also i said using format in question title :)

Comment: In [20]: a=2

In [21]:  print(f"{a * 3}".format(a=3))
what would you expect 9..sorry its 6

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
print((int(f"{{a}}".format(a=2)))*3)
```

Comment: as i said a wont use `eval` (or `int` or `float` for ...) functions!

Comment: ohh k, you just mentioned eval in your question.

Comment: Actually, you didn't say anything about int or float functions